# How to get sink elements from a pipeline?

Tags: video, gstreamer

I have a pipeline, which is created by using the below function

```
gst_parse_launch(char * string);
```

Now I would like to overlay the video, in my WID. For that I need to get the sink element.

How to get the Sink element from above pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set an element name, e.g.: `fakesink name="mysink"` and when the pipeline has been created use: `gst_bin_get_by_name(pipeline, "mysink")`.